# how to replace a function call in static library

Tags: c, linux

I have several `.a` files and `.o` files to be linked as an elf file. Suppose that `.a` files are `libaa.a`, `libbb.a`, `libcc.a` and `.o` files are `1.o`, `2.o` and `3.o`. Each `.a` and `.o` has an unlinked function `char *common_func(int a)`. What I want to do is to replace all `common_func` called in `libbb.a` and `2.o` with my own `self_common_func`. Is there any solutions?

PS.

1. I do not have any source code except the definition of function `self_common_func`.
2. the definition of `common_func` is defined in c stdlib.

Comment: Where is `common_func` defined? In one of the libraries? Do you just want to replace the definition of `common_func` with your own and have it be the one that is called?

Comment: You can use ar on static libraries

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I have updated.

Comment: With ordinary functions, it is not necessary to change its definition in a library in order to have other modules in that and other libraries call it—you simply define it in your sources and ensure the object containing it is linked first. Then the linker will use it and will resolve any references to the routine name to your routine. Problems can arise if the routine is defined in the library in a module that defines other symbols too and there are any references to those symbols. Then the linker will pull in that module to resolve the other references, and there will be two definitions.

Comment: However, with a routine in the standard C library, its semantics may be known by the C compiler, and calls to it may be replaced during compilation. E.g., `sqrt(9)` may be replaced by three, `printf("Hello, world.\n")` may be replaced by `puts("Hello, world.\n")`, `memcpy(&a, &b, n)` might be replaced by a load of n bytes and store of n bytes, and so on. GCC and Clang have a switch to turn off the compiler’s special treatment of functions, so you would need to compile with that.

Comment: With static libraries, you can use `ar` to remove modules from libraries. That may not give anything that simply defining the function yourself will not—if the module you remove contains only the one function, removing it will be fine, and the linker will use your function, but, if the module defines other symbols too and your program uses them, removing the module will leave your program with undefined symbols.